# How can i change Azure SQL online time

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to set my database online/offline status. How can i do?
For example like monday-saturday time 06.00 - 21.00 set online, sunday offline

Comment: Please take a look at the *serverless* tier, which supports this. You can't pause a non-serverless SQL Database instance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no default option in Azure SQL to accomplish your scanrio.

Howeever, you may able to do some workaround to get what you want or at least most of it.

For example:

- you could leverage Azure SQL Serverless. A lot of considerations need to put here.
- Azure SQL Managed Instance
- Deploy SQL Server inside Azure VM. This involves a lot of work and maintenance.

Here's some docs that can help :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/sql-managed-instance-paas-overview